# Grabbing the parameters from a pushed URL in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, webforms

I am trying to use services of a 3rd party REST API, where they push the parameters onto my URL. Something like:

```
http://domainname/location.aspx?information=MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS AM/PM
```

where domainname is my website, while location.aspx is my page which will read the parameters being pushed. 
How do I grab the "information" parameter in ASP.NET Web Forms C#? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string information = Request["information"];
```

Comment: Or Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["information"]) if you want to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
string information = Request.QueryString["information"]
```

there is also jquery/javascript way of doing it. [refer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript)